# Why does Windows sometimes use a critical section and sometimes use an atomic list for the heap lock?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I encountered a problem where during a parallelized operation, I get a severe performance issue on certain machines. For example, the code below scales well on a 2 chip machine with 8 cores each, but scales poorly on a 2 chip machine with 10 cores each.

The profiler indicates cache misses for the machine with 2x10 cores and indicates calls to the Windows `RtlEnterCriticalSection`. Most time here is spent on malloc/free. For the 2x8 core machine, most time is spent on the `std::rand` (the bare matrix matrix product is just to introduce some dummy number crunching).

For the 2x8 core machine, I don't get any cache misses at all, and I also dont' see calls to `RtlEnterCriticalSection`. Instead I see calls to `RtlInterlockedPopSList` which looks like Windows is using atomics to manage the heap lock. The question is why would it use the critical section on the other machine which is highly inefficient for multi-threading?

```
     std::vector> futures;
     for (auto iii = 0; iii != 40; iii++) {
         futures.push_back(std::async([]() {
             for (auto i = 0; i != 100000 / 40; i++) {
                 const int size = 10;
                 for (auto k = 0; k != size * size; k++) {
                     double* matrix1 = (double*)malloc(100 * sizeof(double));
                     double* matrix2 = (double*)malloc(100 * sizeof(double));
                     double* matrix3 = (double*)malloc(100 * sizeof(double));

                     for (auto i = 0; i != size; i++) {
                         for (auto j = 0; j != size; j++) {
                             matrix1[i * size + j] = std::rand() / RAND_MAX;
                             matrix2[i * size + j] = std::rand() / RAND_MAX;
                         }
                     }

                     for (auto i = 0; i != size; i++) {
                         for (auto j = 0; j != size; j++) {
                             double sum = 0.0;
                             for (auto k = 0; k != size; k++) {
                                 sum += matrix1[i * size + k] * matrix2[k * size + j];
                             }
                             matrix3[i * size + j] = sum;
                         }
                     }
                     free(matrix1);
                     free(matrix2);
                     free(matrix3);
                 }
             }
         }));
     }
     for (auto& entry : futures)
       entry.wait();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason why you're allocating and freeing the arrays inside a large loop? For performance reasons, wouldn't it be better to just allocate them once?

Comment: Which versions of Windows?

Comment: Critical Sections attempt to use an interlocked operation if contention is low enough. More cores -> more contention -> less often it can get away with the spin interlock operation.

Comment: Agreed that it would be better to have the allocation outside the loop (or even memory pools per thread), but for the actual program I use libraries inside the loop that don't allow definition of an external allocator. This is for Windows 7 Professional 64-bit, but Windows 10 seems to have the same issue.

Comment: Is there any control over the threshold when the interlocked operation vs. full mutex is used? I suppose this is related to the total number of threads of the process as well?